# Custom Formula in Condition Format Rule Builder Script

Tags: google-apps-script, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a custom formula that I've been using within the conditional formatting rules. However I am trying to write a script that builds the rules automatically on open so that they 'reset' to the correct order (the ranges get messed up when rearranging cells) The code I currently have is:

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("C1:D600");

  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
                           .whenFormulaSatisfied(=$E1="x")
                           .setBackground("red")
                           .setRanges([range])
                           .build();

  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();

  rules.push(rule);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}
```

In the conditional formatting menu I have it set to Custom Formula Is... =$E1="x"

How can I get that formula to work within the script conditional format rule builder? I get syntax errors for it currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to place the formula in quotation marks as it is a string:

```
'=$E1="x"'
```